# req.flash() requires session

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I got the problem on a route (register) :

```
TypeError: req.flash is not a function
    at /Users/laurent/Projects/perso/express-live-stream/server/routes/register.js:11:32
```

Setup in app.js

```
const Session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(Session({
    store: new FileStore({
        path : './server/sessions'
    }),
    secret: config.server.secret,
    cookie: {maxAge: Date().now + (60 * 1000 * 30) } ,
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(flash());
```

Router (routes/register.js)

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    passport = require('passport');

router.get('/',
    require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedOut(),
    (req, res) => {
        res.render('register', {
            user : null,
            errors : {
                username : req.flash('username'), <== problem here (line 11)
                email : req.flash('email')
            }
        });
    });
```

It seems my setup is ok as flash messages are stored in sessions.
I checked before in Google but didn't find anything

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem
wrong order I should declare router before flash